# GPG error, but could not update public key

Tags: apt, gnupg

When I ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I got these errors:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059
W: Failed to fetch https://cli.github.com/packages/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

So following other answers here, I tried to update the key using this:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 23F3D4EA75716059
```

Which returned this:

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.UZIznQa775/gpg.1.sh --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 23F3D4EA75716059
gpg: key 23F3D4EA75716059: public key "GitHub CLI <opensource+cli@github.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

But when I run "sudo apt-get update" again, I get the same errors (see above) again.

I'm pretty much a Linux newbie.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Here's the output of cat /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` partner
```

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @Rishon JR See edited question with the output you requested.

Comment: Your sources look fine... There's something wrong with the key. Try `sudo apt-key del 23F3D4EA75716059 && sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key C99B11DEB97541F0 && sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @Rishon JR Before I run your code, want to check the key in the second command, starts with C99B....  Shouldn't that key be the same as the one in the first command: starts with 23F3... ?

Comment: I looked it up again... and it's the correct key for ubuntu 20.04. (I would recommend upgrading to ubuntu 22.04 LTS using `sudo do-release-upgrade`). If you are not willing to upgrade, do `sudo apt-key del 23F3D4EA75716059 && sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-key C99B11DEB97541F0 && sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @RishonJR No luck. "apt-get update" returns exactly the same errors re NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059.  I would like to upgrade to 22.04 LTS but cannot; if I run do-upgrade-release, I get "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.".

Comment: Make a live USB and use that to upgrade (In the install options there will be upgrade ubuntu alongside reinstall ubuntu and other options as well).

Comment: Hi Rick, Any update?

Comment: @Rishon_JR Just saw this and I'll give it a try.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll let you know how it works.

Comment: @Rishon_JR.  Sheesh, I've messed up.  I created a LiveUSB with 22.04.  Installed 22.04 but selected "Install along side 20.04" since I was afraid of messing up my current set up.  But now I'm really messed up since none of my Home files and apps are available when I boot into 22.04.  I should have realized this was happening when the install process forced me to create another partition (for 22.04).  Can I unroll this somehow and install 22.04 on top of and in place of 20.04?

Comment: Let's move the discussion to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144395/ricks-help-room).

Comment: I have the same issue. How is this eventually fixed?